# Set different emailaddress for different projects in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops

In the overview of the "Visual Studio Team Services Accounts" I am connected to 2 different projects.

One project is named xxxx.visualstudio.com and the other is named yyyy.visualstudio.com.

I, in this case, is my Microsoft account. For this Microsoft account I can store 1 'contact email' address.

Is there a way to set a different email address for every project for my notifications?
I would like all the notifications (for instance about the code reviews) for project A to go to emailaddress 1 and for project B to go emailaddress 2.

Is that possible?

EDIT
I added a screenprint of the screen I see.
In that screenprint there is (in the red square) the dropdown box with the 2 'names' in it. One says 'Microsoft account' (which I understand, because I'm logged on with it) and the other one states my full name, but I have no clue where it comes from.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only change the `Contact e-mail` from "`My profile`" in VSTS for future communications like alerts and service notifications.

But your account name cannot be changed as you mentioned : "`One project is named xxxx.visualstudio.com and the other is named yyyy.visualstudio.com.`"

So, in your scenario if you want to work on the 2 different projects at the same time, then it's impossible. Once the `Contact e-mail` changed, it will be used to all the projects.

However you can apply for two VSTS accounts with different email addresses, then use them separately for the two projects.

---

**UPDATE:**

For the listed accounts, actually they are related to same Microsoft account, just access to different sites/services in Azure, and show the `Full Name` in the services.

Back to your original question, just as I said in above answer you can not use different email address for your account in multiple projects **at the same time**.

However you can enter another different email address to receive the alerts/notifications when you create the subscriptions:

[image]

Comment: I can see a dropdown at the `https://app.vsaex.visualstudio.com/me` page with 2 'names' (one says 'microsoft account' and the other says my full name). They both seem to be coupled to my microsoft account I use to login. My 2 projects are both coupled to the user named 'microsoft account' (so they share the same email address). I'm not sure where the other user comes from and how I can change the project to belong to that other user.

Comment: @Michel What's that mean for `2 names`? Could you please share the screenshot here? Based on my test the only account is the `'microsoft account'`, the full name is just the display name /nickname of your account. If other account is added as a member of your projects, then it will display as a member such like `xxxx.visualstudio.com (Member) ` on that page.

Comment: added the screenprint

Comment: @Michel Actually they are related to same Microsoft account, just access different sites/services in Azure, and show the `Full Name` in the services. Back to your original question, just as I said in above answer you can not use different email address for your account in multiple projects **at the same time**.  However you can enter another different email address when you create the subscriptions, see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. However, I wonder why you mention the "sites/services in Azure"? I indeed have two accounts in Azure (well, actually one is deleted), but how do the Azure accounts relate to my accounts/data in visualstudio.com?

Comment: @Michel I guess the Azure account is created based on the Microsoft account (I am in  this case), besides Azure services may grand the permission for VSTS account to access them... or [Access VSTS with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/organizations/accounts/access-with-azure-ad?view=vsts)...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. When you go to "My profile" in VSTS. Then select the project you want to change in the dowpdown. Then click the "Edit profile" and change the email to the email you want to use.

You do need to verify the email you want to use.